# Turn a set of 3d coordinates into polygonal "landscape" in Java

Tags: java, 3d, geometry, processing, polygons

I'm working on a visualization project. From the data I have calculated the X, Y, and Z coordinates for a large set of points. Using Processing it was very simple to draw this out with lines and dots.

From the top it looks like this:

[image: Top down view]

And from a side angle you can see how it occupies 3D space

[image: 3D view from side]

The part I'm struggling with is turning this into polygons. I need the end result to be something I can export as a .obj file, and then later open in Blender or similar 3D modelling programs.

The two main issues are that these points are not on a grid, but are instead organized in a circle based on radian angles, and that the triangle structure isn't all that simple.

I tried drawing out my own polygons (it's kinda sorta working), but I'm getting to the point where the maths are getting a bit too complex to handle and my code is bloated with arrays, if statements, and for loops...

[image: it's kinda sorta working]

Surely there must be a better way? Are there any plugins maybe that would help me with this task? Or some techniques I should take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

Processing has `screenX()` and `screenY()` functions that take a 3D point and return a 2D point. That sounds like pretty much exactly what you're looking for. Please see [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/screenX_.html) for more info.

Comment: That sadly doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. I'm trying to turn my 3d coordinates into a functional 3d mesh, not simply a 2d image :(